# Como bloquear requisições externas no Jboss?

Tags: java, jboss

Como bloquear uma aplicação externa de acessar minha aplicação web? Existem alguma forma de bloquear isso?

Answer (score 1):

No jBoss versões mais antigas, você pode passar o parâmetro -b X.X.X.X para somente sua máquina poder fazer requisição ao Jboss.

Fonte: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Getting_Started_Guide/Starting_and_Stopping_the_Server.html

Na versão mais nova do Jboss utilize o parâmetro -Djboss.bind.address=X.X.X.X

Onde, X.X.X.X é seu ip.

Answer (score -1):

Veja se te ajuda:

https://ashishpshukla.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/how-to-restrict-access-to-your-web-application-on-the-jboss-5-0-application-server/

1. Identify the web application that needs to be restricted access to (Lets call this as ABCWebApp). Update the web.xml file, you will probably need to add the following lines:

File:        /usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ABCWebApp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<!– add a security-contraint to

a resource in your application that needs to be

restricted –>

<security-constraint>

<web-resource-collection>

<web-resource-name>Secure Content</web-resource-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

<!– if you need any particular directory, you can have the pattern as /dir_name/* –>

</web-resource-collection>

<auth-constraint>

<role-name>ABCWebAppUser</role-name>

</auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<!– define the type of authentication mechanism to be used –>

<login-config>

<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>

<realm-name>ABCWebApp – Restricted Zone</realm-name>

</login-config>

<!– defie the role that are allowed to access the restricted zone –>

<security-role>

<description>The role required to access restricted content </description>

<role-name>ABCWebAppUser</role-name>

</security-role>
```

2. Add or update the existing jboss-web.xml file under your web application to use the security policy

File: /usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ABCWebApp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>

<jboss-web>

<context-root />

java:/jaas/ABCWebApp_Policy

<!– This policy needs to be defined in the login-config.xml –>

</jboss-web>
```

3. Define the policy in step 2 in login-config.xml. Add following lines

File: /usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/login-config.xml

```
<!– A template configuration for the ABCWebApp web application. This

defaults to the UsersRolesLoginModule the same as other and should be

changed to a stronger authentication mechanism as required.

–>

<application-policy name=”ABCWebApp_Policy”>

<authentication>

<login-module code=”org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule”

flag=”required”>

<!– define property file which has username / password –>

<module-option name=”usersProperties”>props/ABCWebApp_Policy-users.properties</module-option>

<!– define property file which has role for the above users –>

<module-option name=”rolesProperties”>props/ABCWebApp_Policy-roles.properties</module-option>

</login-module>

</authentication>

</application-policy>
```

4. Create the property file for the user credentials (defied in step 3)

File: /usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/props/ABCWebApp_Policy-users.properties

```
# A sample users.properties file for use with the UsersRolesLoginModule

ashish = pass1234

shukla = pass1234

ashishshukla = pass1234

ashishpshukla = pass1234
```

5. Create the property file for the user roles (defied in step 3), Note the roles should be as defined in step 1

File: /usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/props/ABCWebApp_Policy-roles.properties

```
ashish = ABCWebAppUser

shukla = ABCWebAppUser

ashishshukla = ABCWebAppUser

ashishpshukla = ABCWebAppUser
```

Comment: Pq fui negativado?